# How to export multiple tracks with the same instrument?

Tags: export, sound

When you have multiple instruments, multiple MIDI tracks are generated on export:

```
s = Sound[{SoundNote["C", {0, 0.3}, "Tuba"], 
    SoundNote["G", {0.1, 0.5}, "Cello"]}];
Export["~/Downloads/test.mid", s];
SystemOpen@"~/Downloads/test.mid"
```

[image]

But not when you don't use the same instrument:

```
s = Sound[{SoundNote["C", {0, 0.3}, "Piano"], 
    SoundNote["G", {0.1, 0.5}, "Piano"]}];
Export["~/Downloads/test.mid", s];
SystemOpen@"~/Downloads/test.mid"
```

[image]

Is there some way to specify multiple tracks with Sound or SoundNote without using different instruments?